# How to position an tooltip fixed?

Tags: html, css, sass

I created an clickable tooltip that disappears when you click outside the card or in the icon, but when i click to show the tooltip and scroll up or down the page, the tooltip card follows. But i want it to be fixed where i opened it.

```
.tooltip {
  margin: 0 0.15rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  icon {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1.0rem;
    width: 1.0rem;
    height: 1.0rem;
  }
}
```

I tried position: fixed, but it doesn't work.

Update: the tooltip don't scroll with the page anymore, i used ::ng-deep to access the class and set position: absolute, but its style is wrong.

Comment: Position: fixed means the item is fixed on the viewport. So it should be posited on the viewport.

Comment: So it wouldn't solve my problem anyway...the card is ok, but i don't know why it isn't fixed where it should be.

Comment: If you want to do it, you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: I'm working with Typescript, what do you suggest to create this function? Use scrollTop?

Comment: How did you made that tooltip appear?

Comment: Using an external design library, i only put (libraryName) = "click" in the HTML button element and it will open the tip when clicked. I can't say the name because it's corporative and it has very strong privacy rules. And i'm using Angular 10 as well

Comment: Update: the tooltip don't scroll with the page anymore, i used ::ng-deep to access the class and set position: absolute, but its style is wrong.